# Instance of an object as BackgroundWorker argument

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arguments

is there a way to pass the instance of a class as an argument for BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()? I want to do this to being able to access a metod of the instance and then with this data update a ProgressBar showing the current progress.
Slightly modified code:

```
public class Player 
{
    public void Open(string file)
    {
        string command = "open \"" + file + "\" type MPEGVideo alias canc";
        mciSendString(command, null,0,0);
    }

    public string Progress ()
    {
        StringBuilder position = new StringBuilder(200);
        string command = "status canc position";
        mciSendString(command, position, 200, 0);
        return position.ToString();
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        string command = "play canc";
       mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
    }

}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Player song = new Player();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            song.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        song.Play();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(song);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Player rola = (Player)e.Argument;
        int progress
        int.TryParse(rola.Progress(), out progress);
        Debug.WriteLine(rola.Progress());
        Debug.WriteLine(progress);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Right now the output in console of the code is a null string and a cero, the same happens when there's no file playing, so my conclusion is that this is happening because BackgroundWorker is not taking the instance of Player

Comment: You are passing an instance of `Player`, but then trying to cast it to `Something`. Your code example isn't complete so it's not clear what `Something` is never mind why you think you can cast `Player` to `Something`. But if that's real code, then it seems likely your worker just fails immediately at the invalid cast, so of course nothing happens.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Oops, sorry. It was supposed to be Player not Something, I wrote that by accident while translating the code from my native language to English so I could make it clearer.

Comment: Don't translate the code, unless you are doing it in the IDE and have compiled it. The code that winds up in your question should be directly copy/paste straight from a project that compiles and runs as well as can be expected given the question (i.e. if you have a compiler error you're asking about, obviously the code won't compile).

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to pass the instance of a class as an argument for BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()?

It's not necessary.  `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` is an instance method of `Form1` and so can directly access the `song` field.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    song.Play();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
     // ...do something with song
     // e.g.
     // song.Play();

     worker.ReportProgress (...);
     // ...
}
```

Comment: What you wrote above is true, but does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: The one question asked is _"is there a way to pass the instance of a class as an argument for BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()?"_. An implicitly presented question is "[why is it that] Right now the output in console of the code is a null string and a cero [sic]?" Your answer addresses _neither_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho _"[The answer can be **don’t do that**, but it should also include **try this instead**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)"_.  Honestly, why bother passing an instance when he can access it directly

Comment: "Don't do that" is not in any possible way an answer to "why does this happen?" You also have no reason to believe that the OP requires passing an instance to the worker only in this exact scenario; it's entirely plausible and useful to pass a reference to an object _not_ referenced by any variable accessible by the `DoWork` handler. You've unnecessarily narrowed the question, side-stepping it entirely. And if you _really_ believe this is a valid answer, then you should have voted to close the question as a duplicate of any one of the many other Q&A on SO where the answer is "make it a field".

Comment: Weird, this didn't work. As another test I added Debug.WriteLine(song.Progress()) to other method of Form and I'm able to obtain the expected output, but if I do the same inside bw_DoWork it just prints an empty string.